Why Balarama is known as Samkarshana?
Why is Balarama known as Samkarshana? It sounds like something to do with agriculture. He also holds a plough. Was there any connection of Balarama with agriculture?

Because he was transferred from Dhevakis womb to Rohini. The word for that is Karshana meaning to pull if I am not wrong

I) Your first question Why Balarama is known as Saṃkarṣaṇa?
Srimad Bhāgavata Puranam [Skanda-10 Chapter-1 and Chapter-2] describes the events related to the birth of Sri Balrama as follows:

The Bhagavan as the Antaryami(Witness) of everything tells the
creative power of His unified consciousness ‘yogamaya’ about His plan
for His own birth as Balarama and Krishna. He begins with Balarama.
“The whole of Shesha, which is my abode, will become an embryo in
Devaki's womb which you shall transplant to Rohini's womb.” He was
delivered from the womb of Rohini. Hence, Balarama was residing in two
separate wombs. Firstly Devaki‘s and secondly Rohini’s. His conception
and implantation occurred in the womb of Devaki at first and later
transferred as an embryo to the womb of Rohini next. The transfer of
pregnancy was successful and Balarama was delivered after completion
of pregnancy in the womb of Rohini. Thus this is a unique birth that
took place which has been described in the scriptures.

The original Sanskrit version related to the birth of Balarama
is from Srimad Bhāgavata puranam, Skanda-10, Chapter-1(Slokas: 8-9) and Chapter-2(Slokas: 4-15), authored by Vyāsa Bhagavān:

अध्याय-१

रोहिण्यास्तनयः प्रोक्तो रामः सङ्कर्षणस्त्वया ।
देवक्या गर्भसम्बन्धः कुतो देहान्तरं विना ॥ १.८॥
कस्मान्मुकुन्दो भगवान् पितुर्गेहाद्व्रजं गतः ।
क्व वासं ज्ञातिभिः सार्धं कृतवान् सात्वताम्पतिः ॥ १.९॥

अध्याय-२

एके तमनुरुन्धाना ज्ञातयः पर्युपासते ।
हतेषु षट्सु बालेषु देवक्या औग्रसेनिना ॥ २.४॥    
सप्तमो वैष्णवं धाम यमनन्तं प्रचक्षते ।
गर्भो बभूव देवक्या हर्षशोकविवर्धनः ॥ २.५॥    
भगवानपि विश्वात्मा विदित्वा कंसजं भयम् ।
यदूनां निजनाथानां योगमायां समादिशत् ॥ २.६॥    
गच्छ देवि व्रजं भद्रे गोपगोभिरलङ्कृतम् ।
रोहिणी वसुदेवस्य भार्याऽऽस्ते नन्दगोकुले ।
अन्याश्च कंससंविग्ना विवरेषु वसन्ति हि ॥ २.७॥     
देवक्या जठरे गर्भं शेषाख्यं धाम मामकम् ।
तत्सन्निकृष्य रोहिण्या उदरे सन्निवेशय ॥ २.८॥    
अथाहमंशभागेन देवक्याः पुत्रतां शुभे ।
प्राप्स्यामि त्वं यशोदायां नन्दपत्न्यां भविष्यसि ॥ २.९॥     
अर्चिष्यन्ति मनुष्यास्त्वां सर्वकामवरेश्वरीम् ।
धूपोपहारबलिभिः सर्वकामवरप्रदाम् ॥ २.१०॥
नामधेयानि कुर्वन्ति स्थानानि च नरा भुवि ।
दुर्गेति भद्रकालीति विजया वैष्णवीति च ॥ २.११॥    
कुमुदा चण्डिका कृष्णा माधवी कन्यकेति च ।
माया नारायणीशानी शारदेत्यम्बिकेति च ॥ २.१२॥     
गर्भसङ्कर्षणात्तं वै प्राहुः सङ्कर्षणं भुवि ।
रामेति लोकरमणाद्बलं बलवदुच्छ्रयात् ॥ २.१३॥     
सन्दिष्टैवं भगवता तथेत्योमिति तद्वचः ।
प्रतिगृह्य परिक्रम्य गां गता तत्तथाकरोत् ॥ २.१४॥    
गर्भे प्रणीते देवक्या रोहिणीं योगनिद्रया ।
अहो विस्रंसितो गर्भ इति पौरा विचुक्रुशुः ॥ २.१५॥

Chapter-1

Sankarsana (Balarama) was (first) referred to by you as a son of Rohini. 
How could his connection be conceived with the womb of Devakit 
without his assuming another body ॥ 1.8 ॥

Wherefore did Lord Sri Krsna [the Bestower of Liberation] shift to Vraja 
from His father's residence [at Mathura]? 
And where [in what different places] did that Lord of the Yadus take up His abode
alongwith His kinsfolk? ॥ 1.9 ॥

Chapter-2
 
Remaining faithful to him, a few kinsmen [of theirs, however,] continued
to serve him. When six boys of Devaki had been killed by Kamsa [the son of Ugrasena],
a ray of Lord Visnu, whom the devotees speak of as Lord Ananta,
entered the womb of Devaki as her seventh child, 
that went to enhance her delight and grief at the same time.॥ 2.4 & 2.5 ॥

Perceiving the fear born of Kamsa to the Yadus, His proteges,
the Lord too, the Soul of the universe, commanded [as follows] 
Yogamaya [His transcendent creative energy] ॥ 2.6 ॥

Proceed, O good goddess, to Vraja enriched by cowherds and cows.
Rohini, Vasudeva’s wife, is staying in the village of Gokula owned by Nanda;
and, afraid of Kamsa, his other wives too are residing in secret places. ॥ 2.7 ॥

There exists in Devaki's womb, in the form of an embryo, My own part manifestation
known by the name of Sesa [the serpent-god]. Taking it out, 
place it in the womb of Rohini.॥ 2.8 ॥

Then | shall assume the role of a son of Devaki with all My divine potencies,
which constitute so many parts of My being as it were, O blessed lady; 
while you shall be born of Yasoda, the wife of Nanda.॥ 2.9 ॥

People will worship you by means of incense, _ Offerings of food and other presents,
recognizing you as the supreme controller [of the destinies] of men 
seeking various boons and as the bestower of all desired blessings.॥ 2.10 ॥

Men will erect temples [sacred to you] on earth and give [diverse] appellations 
[to you] such as Durgā, Bhadrakāli, Vijayā, Vaisnavi, Kumudā, Candikā, Krsnā,      
Mādhavi and Kanyakā, Māyā, Narāyani, Isāni, Sāradā and Ambikā.॥ 2.11 & 2.12 ॥

People on earth will call the son of Rohini Saṃkarṣaṇa, particularly because of
his being taken out of the womb [of Devaki]; by the name of "Rama" because of his
giving delight to the world and "Bala" because of his preeminence among those 
possessed of strength.॥ 2.13 ॥

Thus instructed by the Lord and accepting His command with the words, "O yes,
let it be so!" and going round Him from left to right [as a mark of respect],
the goddess descended on earth and carried out His behest as she was told.॥ 2.14 ॥

When the embryo in the womb of Devaki was transferred to that of Rohini by
Yogamaya [who represents the Lord's trance-sleep at the time of universal dissolution],
the people of Mathura wailed aloud saying,
“Ah! the embryo [in the womb of Devaki] has perished!॥ 2.15 ॥


The answer to your question lies in sloka SB [10.2.13] as given above. Let us reproduce it again in order to have some clarity:

गर्भसङ्कर्षणात्तं वै प्राहुः सङ्कर्षणं भुवि ।
रामेति लोकरमणाद्बलं बलवदुच्छ्रयात् ॥ १०.२.१३॥
People on earth will call the son of Rohini Saṃkarṣaṇa[संकर्षण], particularly because of
his being taken out of the womb [of Devaki]; by the name of Rāma[राम] because of his
giving delight to the world and Bala[बल] because of his preeminence among those
possessed of strength.॥ 10.2.13 ॥

Beware: The Meaning associated with word Saṃkarṣaṇa(संकर्षण) are (1) Attracting, (2) Ploughing and (3) Balarama [brother of Krishna].
In this context, the meaning of Saṃkarṣaṇa**(संकर्षण) is "Attracting" or in other words "dragging away". That is, Balarama is the one who was dragged away [from womb of Devaki], so His epithet Sankarshana.
II) Your second and final question It sounds like something to do with agriculture. He also holds a plough. Was there any connection of Balarama with agriculture?
Sakra (शक्र) is a Sanskrit word meaning ""mighty"" or "powerful," and is used as an epithet of Indra in hymn 5.34 of the Rigveda. Indra is praised as the highest god in 250 hymns of the Rigveda.

Indra was widely worshipped in Tamil Nadu, where a big festival
called Indra Vizha(இந்திர விழா/Festival of Indra) was celebrated in
His honor by Choza Kings in Pūmpukar. Agricultural communities
worship him to bring timely rains. Devotion to him brings human
prosperity and happiness.
It is also well known in Mahābhāratam, the Yadava clan worshipped
Indra for rains for agriculture and Lord Krishna’s childhood involved the lifting of Govardhan Hill.

Unlike Indra, Sesa (Serpant-god) is not known for agriculture. But in the avatāra of Sesa as Balarāma, He carries a Hala(हल/Plough) resting on his shoulders. There are two meaning associated with Hala: (1) A weapon peculiar to Balarāma and (2) an agricultural implement used for turning over, and partly pulverising soil.
As a Hala Wielder (Haladhara/हलधर), symbolically Balarāma may be associated with agriculture.

Not only because for the possession of the plough, Balarama is recorded to have changed the course of the river Yamuna by creating a furrow with his plough. For peasants accustomed to digging canals to irrigate their fields, this sounds close to home.

@অনু  I Would have definitely agreed with you, had Balarama have such motive of canal digging. But Balarama called out Yamuna to take a dip in the water but she refused. With angry, Balarama pulled Yamuna with his plough towards him. Terrified Yamuna begged for forgiveness which was granted. Finally Balarama had his dip happily. In this story Balarama's intention of using his plough was to teach a lesson to Yamuna. However if the changed course of river used for agriculture later, then it is deemed only as side effect.  https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-vishnu-purana/d/doc57635.html
